# I have tried to convert the data type, but it just won't work.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, types

I keep getting the wrong message... what's wrong with my code? Thanks

I have tried to convert the data type, but it just won't work.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dictionary ????

This what the console keeps showing to me:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
        the_winnner_goes_to()
      File "main.py", line 17, in the_winnner_goes_to
        winner_bid_test = int(bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"])
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

The code is here:

```
from replit import clear
#HINT: You can call clear() to clear the output in the console.
from art import logo
print(logo)
print("Welcome to the secret auction program.")

bidder_list = []
def add_new_bidder(bidder_name, bidder_offer):
 bidders_list = {}
 bidders_list["bidder_name"] = bidder_name
 bidders_list["bidder_offer"] = bidder_offer
 bidder_list.append(bidders_list)

def the_winnner_goes_to():
  winner_bid = 0
  for x in bidder_list:
    winner_bid_test = int(bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"])
    if winner_bid_test > winner_bid:
      winner_bid = winner_bid_test
      winner_bid = int(bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"])
  print(winner_bid)

bid_is_on = True

while bid_is_on:
 bidder_name = str(input("What is your name: \n"))
 bidder_offer = int(input("What's your bid:\n $"))
 other_bidders = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'Yes' or 'No': \n").lower()
 if other_bidders == "yes":
   add_new_bidder(bidder_name, bidder_offer)
   clear()
 else:
   add_new_bidder(bidder_name, bidder_offer)
   bid_is_on = False
   the_winnner_goes_to()
   print(bidder_list)
```

Comment: You should try `x["bidder_offer"]`, instead of `bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"]`

Comment: @rish_hyun OMG!!! It works!!! But I don't know why I don't need to add "bidder_list"? Is it because I already have a bidder_list in the vor loop? Thanks so much! I am so new to python! Thanks for helping me!

Comment: It depends on how you want to traverse the list, I have updated my answer :) When you use `x["bidder_offer"]`, here x is dict, so you are actually working on a single dict, but when you use `bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"]`, here `x` is index, so `bidder_list[x]` is a single dict.

Comment: Buddy, if that worked that for you, please tick the answer as accepted, it would motivate me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `bidders_list` is a list of dict.
So it's like

```
bidders_list = [
      {
          "bidder_name"  : xxx,
          "bidder_offer" : yyy
      },
      {
          "bidder_name"  : xxx,
          "bidder_offer" : yyy
      },
      .
      .
      . 
]
```

So you are trying to do this,

```
for x in bidder_list:
    .. bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"] ..
```

which is wrong, so you should

```
for x in bidder_list:
    .. x["bidder_offer"] ..
```

because `x` is dict

If you want to run `bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"]`

```
for x in range(len(bidders_list)):
    .. bidder_list[x]["bidder_offer"] ..
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! I still need to learn a lot to!